# node.js express can't understand path to css files

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, http

I'm trying to load some info on the html page using node.js with the help of the express.

The problem is that when I want to open the main page (it displays all the books from the database), everything works fine - the css and js files are found and applied to the page. But when I load the another page (it displays single book), the only page is loaded (without any css, I mean). Also, these 2 pages are in the same folder.

I have included the folder with styles like this (in server.js file):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/style')));
```

and that piece of code works fine:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM books", function(err, rows) {
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      res.render("../front/index.hbs", {
        books: rows
      });
    });
});
```

but when I try to load this piece - no css applied:

```
app.get("/single-product/:id/", function(req, res){
  const id = req.params.id;
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE idBook=?", [id], function(err, rows) {
     if(err) return console.log(err);
     res.render("../front/single-product.hbs", {
        books: rows[0]
    });
  });
});
```

the css inclusion in both files is the following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Cusom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

when I open the devtools, in the first way it shows 200 response code, in the second - 404. What can be wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212895/discussion-on-question-by-johnythebastard-node-js-express-cant-understand-path).

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve those css files in your html-routes if you have them separate from the api-routes, or just add them to your regular server if you have them together.

Answer (score -1):

Revising: add 'server' to app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server', '/style')));

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, that both files (the one that displayed normally and the second) are in the same folder.

Comment: Oh okay, that gotcha has caught me before, so it's usually a first-check for me--went for the quick fix! haha

Comment: if you have your CSS files nested a bit, you'll have to add that to the path.join, so my 'server' may not even be low enough, you may have to add another level, too. Hope that helps!